# why my own generalized convolution code in C# not working?

Tags: c#

I am trying to create my own generalize convolution code using c# with unsafe block. The idea is to pass the image and the 2D kernel to the convolution function. However, the code works -not sure properly- for 3x3 kernel, but it always give me an error (Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.) for 5x5 or 7x7 kernels. Therefore, if anyone can help with this code but if you please do not give me some ready code (I already have it and it is working from internet). what I want is to have my own understanding of my own code. kindly, please help me to make my code works properly.

```
    public static bool convolveMy(Bitmap img, double[][] kernel)
    {
        Bitmap bSrc = (Bitmap)img.Clone();
        BitmapData bmdata = img.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, img.Width, img.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
        BitmapData bmSrc = bSrc.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, img.Width, img.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

        int stride = bmdata.Stride;
        System.IntPtr Scan0 = bmdata.Scan0;
        System.IntPtr SrcScan0 = bmSrc.Scan0;


        unsafe
        {
            byte* p = (byte*)(void*)Scan0;
            byte* pc = (byte*)(void*)SrcScan0;

            int nOffset = stride - img.Width * kernel.GetLength(0);
            int foff = (kernel.GetLength(0) - 1) / 2;

            for (int y = 1; y < img.Height -1 /*foff*/; y++)
                for (int x = 1; x < img.Width - 1/*foff*/; x++)
                {
                    double[][] bluem = new double[kernel.GetLength(0)][];
                    for (int i = 0; i < kernel.GetLength(0); i++)
                        bluem[i] = new double[kernel.GetLength(0)];
                    double[][] greenm = new double[kernel.GetLength(0)][];
                    for (int i = 0; i < kernel.GetLength(0); i++)
                        greenm[i] = new double[kernel.GetLength(0)];
                    double[][] redm = new double[kernel.GetLength(0)][];
                    for (int i = 0; i < kernel.GetLength(0); i++)
                        redm[i] = new double[kernel.GetLength(0)];

                    //The code below move the pixel components (RGB) to a new array 
                    int StrideMoveOverImg = 0;
                    int moveCountertoNextPixel = 0;
                    int kernelLength = kernel.GetLength(0);
                    for (int fy = 0; fy < kernel.GetLength(0); fy++)
                    {
                        for (int fx = 0; fx < kernel.GetLength(0); fx++)
                        {
                                bluem[fy][fx] = pc[moveCountertoNextPixel + StrideMoveOverImg];
                                ++moveCountertoNextPixel;
                                greenm[fy][fx] = pc[moveCountertoNextPixel + StrideMoveOverImg];
                                ++moveCountertoNextPixel;
                                redm[fy][fx] = pc[moveCountertoNextPixel + StrideMoveOverImg];
                                ++moveCountertoNextPixel;
                        }
                        moveCountertoNextPixel = 0;
                        StrideMoveOverImg += stride;
                    }
                    double cblueSum = 0;
                    double cgreenSum = 0;
                    double credSum = 0;
                    double cblue = 0;
                    double cgreen = 0;
                    double cred = 0;
                    //The code below start multiply the kernel with the image component 
                    //then the final value of the result pixel stored int cblueSum,CgreenSum and CredSum
                    for (int fy = -foff; fy <= foff; fy++)
                    {
                        for (int fx = -foff; fx <= foff; fx++)
                        {
                            cblue = bluem[fy + foff][fx + foff] * kernel[fy + foff][fx + foff];
                            cgreen = greenm[fy + foff][fx + foff] * kernel[fy + foff][fx + foff];
                            cred = redm[fy + foff][fx + foff] * kernel[fy + foff][fx + foff];
                            cblueSum += cblue;
                            cgreenSum += cgreen;
                            credSum += cred;
                        }
                    }
                    //check the result pixel : cBlueSum, CgreenSum,credSum is in the range of pixel value [0:255]
                    if (cblueSum < 0) cblueSum = 0;
                    if (cblueSum > 255) cblueSum = 255;
                    if (cgreenSum < 0) cgreenSum = 0;
                    if (cgreenSum > 255) cgreenSum = 255;
                    if (credSum < 0) credSum = 0;
                    if (credSum > 255) credSum = 255;

                    p[kernel.GetLength(0) + stride] = (byte)cblueSum;
                    p[kernel.GetLength(0) + 1 + stride] = (byte)cgreenSum;
                    p[kernel.GetLength(0) + 2 + stride] = (byte)credSum;

                    p  += kernel.GetLength(0);
                    pc += kernel.GetLength(0);
                }
           p += nOffset;
           pc += nOffset;
        }//unsafe
        img.UnlockBits(bmdata);
        bSrc.UnlockBits(bmSrc);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: This error can be as simple as reading/writing over the bounds of the unsafe memory.  have you debugged this?

Comment: The sizes of you arrays are growing a lot larger with 5x5 and 7x7.  You may be exceeding the size of an int then ending up with a negative index in to your arrays.

Comment: Thank you for your time to understand the code and give me the reason for what happened. If you can please let me know or give some hint how to overcome this problem. My major in image processing and I would like to understand how each technique works from inside through coding not only use it and understand how it work theoretically. I know that when I use 5x5 and 7x7 specially at the end of interpreting the code when it reach the last mask convolution it exceed the size of the image. Thanks Again

Comment: Finally, the code works . Thank you All for helping. What I did is a simple mistake. I thought that the pointer (p) and (pc) should increase by the kernel width. However, the right way is to increase the pointer by the number of bytes inside the pixel and since am using 24byte image therefore I should increase the pointers by 3 so: change the code pc += kernel.GetLength(0); and p += kernel.GetLength(0); to be p += 3; and pc+=3 .  again thank you all for help . BTW if you have any comments or you find that the code may not work properly for any reason please please come up with comments.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the code works . Thank you All for helping. What I did is a simple mistake. I thought that the pointer (p) and (pc) should increase by the kernel width. However, the right way is to increase the pointer by the number of bytes inside the pixel and since am using 24byte image therefore I should increase the pointers by 3 so: change the code pc += kernel.GetLength(0); and p += kernel.GetLength(0); to be p += 3; and pc+=3 . again thank you all for help . BTW if you have any comments or you find that the code may not work properly for any reason please please come up with comments